# Is there anyway to view scheduled local notifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Is there a way to view all of the currently scheduled local notifications for my app?

Just trying to do some debugging, and it would be nice to see the list of notifications, instead of having to wait until they fire.

_mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This gives you an array with all local notifications scheduled. You can loop through it

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
```